# i want two make compare in foreach loop to compare if value of branch from jquery equal to value from foreach then selected it

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a select and get value from jquery and want to compare it with value in foreach if two value id is similar then active the selected value how can I do this is the foreach in blade:

I want two make a comparison in foreach loop to compare if the value of branch from jquery equal to value from foreach then selected it

```html
<select name="branch">
    @foreach($branchs as $branch)
        <option value="{{$branch->id}}">{{$branch->title}}</option>                                              
    @endforeach
</select>
```

```js
 $.ajax({
        url:getHref,
        data:{id:id},
        }).done(function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index,employee){
                $( "input[name*='name']" ).val(employee.name );
                $( "select[name='branch']").val(employee.branch_id);
                $( "select[name='role_id']" ).val(employee.role_id);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to hard coded it since jquery will do the job for you
as you changed the value of select elemnt using jquery
then if the value of `employee.branch_id` meet the value of any option element
then it will automatically selected

```
     $( "select[name='branch']").val(employee.branch_id);
```

and if you want to trigger change event

```
 $( "select[name='branch']").val(employee.branch_id).change();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the code has been successfully implemented, I am happy with it